# String matching with regex

Tags: regex

I have a string with this format MM/YY, MM can be 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 and YY can be 10 to 99  what is the regex corresponding.

I thought `^\d\d/\d\d$`

**edit :**
From the comment bellow
I don't recommand to use regex to make a strict validation of a DateTime.
But in my case a simple match can be done.

**edit :** 
I changed the title because people some people can be maniac

Comment: I'm sure someone will answer your question as written, but validating DateTimes with regex is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: What dialect of regex do you want to use?  Basic?  Extended?  PCRE?

Comment: Just as you don't want months >12, you also don't want to match days that are greater than the allowed value for the particular month, and you'll need to take leap years into account.  As Widor said, regex is the wrong tool.

Comment: I know that regex is a wrong tecno for datetime validation but here I know the format and I just want to check the <=12 validity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
^(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/\d\d$
```

or if the first `0` is optional:

```
^(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])/\d\d$
```

Comment: Thank you my first 0 wasn't optional but as you give two valid answer it's ok

Answer (score 2):

This will allow only 1 to 12 (or 01 to 12): `^(0?[1-9]|1[012])$`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this `^(0|1)\d{1}/\d{2}$` if your months may have leading zeroes. Otherwise `^1?\d{1}\/d{2}$` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Write all possibilities (it's not so long):

```
^(0\d|10|11|12)/\d\d$
```